# how do I pass context variables which use request in Class-based views in django?

Tags: django

In my other views, I am passing in the following context variable.

`tab: 'documents'`
`authenticated: request.user.is_authenticated`
`Exec: ('Exec' in groups)`
`ElectionOfficer: ('ElectionOfficer' in groups)`
`Staff: request.user.is_staff`
`Username: request.user.username`
`URL_ROOT: settings.URL_ROOT`

How can I pass in those exact same variables when accessing the page that renders with the `/multiple` url?

in my `urls.py`

```
url(r'^multiple$', views.SubmissionUploadPage.as_view(), name='multiple_example')
```

in my `forms.py`

```
class MultipleFileExampleForm(BaseForm):
    input_file = MultipleUploadedFileField()

    def save(self):
        example = UserSubmission.objects.create(
            title=self.cleaned_data['title']
        )
        for f in self.cleaned_data['input_file']:
            UploadedFile.objects.create(
                example=example,
                input_file=f
            )

        self.delete_temporary_files()
```

in my `views.py`

```
class BaseFormView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'file_uploads/example_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('success')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(BaseFormView, self).form_valid(form)

class SubmissionUploadPage(BaseFormView):
    form_class = forms.MultipleFileExampleForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `get_context_data`, and inject these values:

```
from django.conf import settings

class BaseFormView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'file_uploads/example_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(
            tab='documents',
            authenticated=self.request.user.is_authenticated,,
            Exec=self.request.users.groups.filter(name='Exec').exists(),
            ElectionOfficer=self.request.users.groups.filter(name='ElectionOfficer').exist(),
            Staff=self.request.user.is_staff,
            Username=self.request.user.username,
            URL_ROOT: settings.URL_ROOT
        )
        return super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('success')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(BaseFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```